# Force.com Platform Developer 1 exam

Tags: force.com

I want to give Platform Developer 1. Is it possible can directly give Platform Developer 1 with out pass/succeeded by App Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the App Builder certification to gain the Platform Developer certification.

From the [official page](http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers) of the Platform Developer exam:

> About the Exam
>
> - **No prerequisites**; recommend taking Apex and Visualforce Controllers (DEV501)

Note that the Apex and Visualforce Controllers course is *recommended*, not required.